# Ember.js and Twitter Bootstrap in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, handlebars.js

I would like to use a twitter bootstrap layout in my Ember.js driven Rails Application.

I am wondering if anyone knows a good way to integrate the generated **application.html.erb** layout and the ember.js, **application.handlebars** layout?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgrassotti/DyUDT/) (based on tomdale's excellent ember-guides screencast) that shows ember.js + twitter bootstrap.

By default ember will render into the body tag. As long as your application.html.erb loads your ember app plus bootstrap and the required libraries there is no need to make any changes. Then just use bootstrap classes in your handlebars templates. For example:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <a class="brand" href="#">Bloggr</a>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li>{{#linkTo 'posts'}}Posts{{/linkTo}}</li>
      <li>{{#linkTo 'about'}}About{{/linkTo}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
{{outlet}}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The fiddle and the preview for Peepcode helped, but as always with most new frameworks/languages just slowing down and reading the guides on Ember.js were most powerful.  As far as editing the application.html.erb file from "rails g bootstrap:layout application fixed"  to work with application.hbs, nope.  Just build the tags you want yourself in you .hbs templates.